# How to make my website scroll smoother with background image?

Tags: html, css

There's a background image that I really like using for my website. For it to look good, I have to use the css, `background-size:cover` and `background-attachment:fixed`. But this makes the scrolling on the page kind of choppy. Is there a way to keep that css, and the same background image, but make the page scroll smoother?

Comment: Could you give an example (perhaps with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) of the choppy scroll effect you're seeing?

Comment: On jsfiddle, the scrolling is fine, only an my actual site is it messed up. I can show you a link to the actual site, but would that be considered spamming?

Comment: @Max I don't think anyone would mind.

Comment: http://tunebuffet.com is the website in question. As you can see, the scrolling is not very smooth.

Comment: @Max Scrolling seems to be choppy initially, but smooth once the whole page has loaded.  Have you tried using a smaller image?

Comment: It's not too bad, but if you compare it with the sites alternate theme (http://tunebuffet.com/themealt.php) the scrolling is far smoother. I was hoping to have the scrolling be equally smooth for both themes? I'll try the smaller image idea, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *massive* background image. 1.43MB to be exact. Once that was loaded completely by my browser ( chrome ) your site scrolled fine.

Use a program like gimp to scale the image down to something manageable. Given the kind of background that you've selected you may be better off with a slightly different image and use of the CSS repeat options.

The effect you're getting would be closely tied to a specific Browser, OS, and the specifications of that computer. For compatibility, keep stuff as minimal as possible.

Rob